# tex4ht fails on rendering \cmark first time, but works second time

Tags: color, tex4ht

Given this MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont} %http : // ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\textcolor{green!80!black}{\ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\textcolor{red}{\ding{55}}}

\begin{document}
\cmark \underline{A}

\cmark \underline{B}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with lualatex gives expected output

[image]

But using `make4ht  -ulm default -a debug report.tex "mathjax,htm"` gives

[image]

It does give this warning

```
l.10 --- TeX4ht warning --- missing \Configure{HColor}{green!80!black}{...} (in
 LaTeX: \\color@green!80!black ) ---
Unsupported font        pzdr
```

But then it is always the first entry which fails, but every use of `\cmark` after that works OK.

Here is the raw HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='report.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='report.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 10 --><p class='noindent'><span id='textcolor1'>80!black!//<span class='pzdr-x-x-109'>✓</span></span><span class='underline'>A</span>
</p><!-- l. 12 --><p class='indent'>   <span id='textcolor2'><span class='pzdr-x-x-109'>✓</span></span><span class='underline'>B</span>
</p>   
 
</body> 
</html>
```

This was checked on Brave browser and Firefox.

Why this happens only on the first one, and how to correct it? How use `\Configure{HColor}` to fix this?

**Update**

I noticed it worked OK when changing `\newcommand{\cmark}{\textcolor{green!80!black}{\ding{51}}}` to `\newcommand{\cmark}{\textcolor{green}{\ding{51}}}`

[image]

So it looks like color mixing is not supported well in tex4ht. Not a big deal. I'll just use `\textcolor{green}` in tex4ht and use `\textcolor{green!80!black}` in PDF for now.

TL 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an error in support for color specifications in the form of `green!80!black` in TeX4ht. I've found where the color specification comes into the document and fixed it. Try this version of `xcolor.4ht`:

```
% xcolor.4ht (2019-04-09-10:06), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2007-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2019 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2019-04-09-10:06}

\input color.4ht
\def\rowc@l@rs[#1]#2#3#4%
 {\global\rownum=\z@
  \global\@rowcolorstrue
  \@ifxempty{#3}%
    {\def\@oddrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
    {\def\@oddrowcolor{\a:rowcolors{#3}%
                       \gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#3}}}}%
  \@ifxempty{#4}%
    {\def\@evenrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
    {\def\@evenrowcolor{\a:rowcolors{#4}%
                        \gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#4}}}}%
  \if@rowcmd
    \def\@rowcolors
     {#1\if@rowcolors
        \o:noalign:{\relax\ifnum\rownum<#2\@norowcolor\else
                 \ifodd\rownum\@oddrowcolor\else\@evenrowcolor\fi\fi}%
      \fi}%
  \else
    \def\@rowcolors
     {\if@rowcolors
        \ifnum\rownum<#2\o:noalign:{\@norowcolor}\else
        #1\o:noalign:{\ifodd\rownum\@oddrowcolor\else\@evenrowcolor\fi}\fi
      \fi}%
  \fi
  \CT@everycr{\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}%
  \ignorespaces}
\NewConfigure{rowcolors}{1}
\def\@rowc@lors{\o:noalign:{\global\advance\rownum\@ne}\@rowcolors}
\def\showrowcolors{\o:noalign:{\global\@rowcolorstrue}\@rowcolors}
\def\hiderowcolors{\o:noalign:{\global\@rowcolorsfalse\@norowcolor}}
\def\:temp#1#2#3{{\set@color}}
\HLet\color@block\:temp
\def\:temp#1#2#3{}
\HLet\boxframe\:temp
\def\strip:fin:excl#1!{#1}
\expandafter\def\csname get!HColor\endcsname#1!#2//{%
  \def\current:color:name{#1\if!#2!\else!\strip:fin:excl#2\fi}%
  \if\relax#2\relax
  %\expandafter\ifx \csname HColor!#1\endcsname\relax
     \let\HColor=\relax
     \expandafter\ifx \csname\string\color @#1\endcsname \relax\else
   \expandafter\ifx \csname colortyp:\endcsname\relax \else
   \extractcolorspec{#1\if!#2!\else!\strip:fin:excl#2\fi}\tmp:color%
   \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tmp:color{HTML}\tmp:color%
   \def\HColor{\#\tmp:color}%
   \Configure{HColor}{\current:color:name}{\HColor}%
      \csname colortyp:\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
         \csname\string\color @#1\expandafter\endcsname
         \space .!//%
\fi \fi
%
  \else
    \ifcsname HColor!#1\endcsname
       \csname HColor!#1\endcsname #2//%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\expandafter\def\csname c:HColor!gray:\endcsname{%
     \expandafter\def\csname HColor!gray\endcsname##1!##2//}
\Configure{HColor!gray}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}
\expandafter\def\csname c:HColor!rgb:\endcsname{%
     \expandafter\def\csname HColor!rgb\endcsname##1,##2,##3!##4//}
\Configure{HColor!rgb}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}
\expandafter\def\csname c:HColor!cmyk:\endcsname{%
     \expandafter\def\csname HColor!cmyk\endcsname##1,##2,##3,##4!##5//}
\Configure{HColor!cmyk}{\Configure{HColor}{}{}}

\def\get:xcolorcss#1#2{%
   \expandafter\extractcolorspec\expandafter{#1}{\tsf:color}%
   \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tsf:color{HTML}\tsf:color%
   \edef#2{\#\tsf:color}%
}


\Hinput{xcolor}
\endinput
```

The fix was necessary in the `\get!HColor` macro, it called a control sequence that contained color name without checking if it exists. As it doesn't exist for this type of specification, the parameter for that control sequence ends up in the document, instead of being eaten.

This is the result:

[image]